# How to load a MSSQL DB using MySQL in Ubuntu

Tags: mysql, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008, ubuntu

I have a MSSQL DB, and would like to convert it to a MySQL DB so I could browse it from Ubuntu. What packages/tools do I need to install and what are the steps for achieving this?
Thanks

Comment: Consider posting on http://serverfault.com/, as this is off topic here

Answer (score 1):

Try [Omegasync](http://www.spectralcore.com/omegasync/) to transform it to MySql